# Use python3-pytz for an Application in Krogoth branch in yocto

Tags: python, python-3.x, yocto

I am dependent on a board whose development is on the **Krogoth** branch in Yocto.

The problem is when looking through the layers for the **krogoth** layer I obtain a `python-pytz` recipe which is dependent on `meta-python` and works only with python2.7. My application for which I am writing a recipe is Python3 dependent.

I tried this by adding it to my `local.conf` as follows:

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-pytz"
```

which throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'python3-pytz'
```

on the contrary when I use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pytz"` the `bitbake` process runs successfully and when I try to run the Python3 interpreter on the board as follows:

```
 # python3
 >> import influxdb
 ....
 No module pytz found
```

On the contrary when I run `python` which opens the 2.7 interpreter:

```
  # python
  >> import pytz

  .. no module threading.
```

which is okay since I have not included `python-threading` in `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`.

How do I use `python3-pytz` which is not available on **krogoth**'s `meta-python` layer?

There is a `python3-pytz` in a [`meta-homeassitant`](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/66411/) layer for the **krogoth** branch. I tried adding the layer to my `bblayers.conf` and tried adding `python3-pytz` but throws the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: try to backport the recipe from `meta-python`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk is there some guide to backport it? I am not aware of how it is done in yocto?

Comment: try to copy it to `krogoth` branch and see it builds; if it doesn't, print - show us the log.

Comment: that worked. I took the `.inc` from the `meta-python` tree and created `python3-pytz_2018.5.bb` in a custom layer under `recipes-devtool/python` folder. Quick question: should all the runtime dependencies be added via `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` in the `local.conf` or will they be automatically be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Oleksandr Kravchuk.

> Backporting to the **Krogoth** branch is the way to obtain pytz in python3

### Quick backporting guide

1. start with your own `meta` layer e.g. `meta-foo`
2. Create `meta-foo/recipes-devtool/python`
3. Add the `python-pytz.inc` file from [Open-Embedded `meta-python`](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-pytz.inc/)
4. Add a recipe titled `python3-pytz_2018.5.bb`

   a. The file contains the following lines:

   ```
   inherit setuptools3
   require python-pytz.inc
   ```
5. add the `meta-foo` in your `bblayers.conf`
6. add the recipe in the `IMAGE_INSTALL_append= " python3-pytz"`
7. `bitbake -k image-name`